# Tensorflow Neural Network faster on CPU than GPU

Tags: performance, tensorflow, neural-network, gpu

I have created a **neural network classifier** with **2** hidden layers. **Hidden Layers** units `[50,25]`.

The model is training much faster on **CPU** than **GPU**.

My questions are :

1. Is this expected? I do see that the architecture is small but not that small to be faster on CPU  :/
2. How should I debug this?
3. I tried increasing batch size, expecting that after some `batch_size` GPU will overtake CPU. But I don't see that happening.

My code is in **Tensorflow 1.4.**

Comment: What GPU, what CPU. Also, when you increase the batch size, is there any differences at all? Are you sure it isn’t running linearly?

Comment: Increasing the batch size will increase the dimension of matrix. And expecting bigger mat_mul would be faster on GPU than CPU. That's the logic behind batch_size thing.

Comment: can you provide your code?

Comment: @random_28, I'm not asking for you to explain your logic- I'm asking if there are any results that show that your code is in fact taking advantage of an increased batch size.

Answer (score 1):

Given the size of the network (very small) I'm inclined to think this is a DMA issue: copying data from the CPU to the GPU is expensive, maybe expensive enough that it makes up for the GPU being much faster at doing larger matrix multiplications.

Comment: My input data is having around 100 features. Is there any way to verify it, that DMA is the issue?

Comment: Generate a timeline, as explained in https://towardsdatascience.com/howto-profile-tensorflow-1a49fb18073d (and many other places). DMAs show up in the timeline

Comment: might increase batch_size